# Como salvar dado tipo map ou array no firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, firestore

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
createProduto(Produto produto){
    Map<String, dynamic> model = {
      "nome" : produto.nome,
      "descricao" : produto.descricao,
      "precoCompra" : produto.precoCompra,
      "itens" : produto.itens // <================ List<Item>
    };

    produtoCollection.add(model).whenComplete(() {
      print(produto.nome + ' cadastrado com sucesso!');
    });
  }
```

Classe item:

```
class Item {
  String nome;
  int quantidade;

  Item({this.nome, this.quantidade});
}
```

Erro:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
>   Invalid argument: Instance of 'Item'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode diretamente inserir uma List de Itens no firebase, você primeiro precisa converter os seus itens para um Map:

```
class Item {
   String nome;
   int quantidade;

   Item({this.nome, this.quantidade});

   Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
      return {
        'nome': nome,
        'quantidade': quantidade
      }
  }
}
```

E non momento de salvar você converte os seus items

```
createProduto(Produto produto){
  Map<String, dynamic> model = {
    "nome" : produto.nome,
    "descricao" : produto.descricao,
    "precoCompra" : produto.precoCompra,
    "itens" : produto.itens.map((item) => item.toMap()).toList() // <- converte os seus itens para uma List<Map<String, dynamic>>
  };

  // Dê preferência por usar async / await nos seus metodos
  produtoCollection.add(model).whenComplete(() {
     print(produto.nome + ' cadastrado com sucesso!');
  });
}
```

De uma olhada neste [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) que vai te ajudar a converter Object a Map ou inversamente, ao invés de ter que escrever para todos os seus modelos os metodos, **toMap** e **fromMap**